# NullPointerException when trying to use ImageView

Tags: reflection, nullpointerexception, imageview

I grabbed the following code from another site - I can't find a problem with it but it keeps giving me a nullpointerexception. The issue I think is right in the first part before the setContentView but including the whole thing just in case. Thanks in advance for the help!

```
public class TileSet extends Activity {

Bitmap originalImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
        R.drawable.announcementbc);

ImageView imageView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub



    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



    //Create an Image view and add our bitmap with reflection to it

    imageView.setImageBitmap(getRefelection(originalImage));

    //imageView.setImageBitmap(image);

    //Add the image to a linear layout and display it
    LinearLayout linLayout = new LinearLayout(this);        
    linLayout.addView(imageView, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    // set LinearLayout as ContentView

    setContentView(linLayout);

}

    // public static Bitmap getRefelection(Bitmap image)

 public static Bitmap getRefelection(Bitmap image)
  {
     //The gap we want between the reflection and the original image
       final int reflectionGap = 4;

       //Get you bit map from drawable folder
       Bitmap originalImage = image;


       int width = originalImage.getWidth();
       int height = originalImage.getHeight();


       //This will not scale but will flip on the Y axis
       Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
       matrix.preScale(1, -1);

       //Create a Bitmap with the flip matix applied to it.
       //We only want the bottom half of the image
       Bitmap reflectionImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalImage, 0, height/2, width, height/2, matrix, false);


       //Create a new bitmap with same width but taller to fit reflection
       Bitmap bitmapWithReflection = Bitmap.createBitmap(width
       , (height + height/2), Config.ARGB_8888);

      //Create a new Canvas with the bitmap that's big enough for
      //the image plus gap plus reflection
      Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmapWithReflection);
      //Draw in the original image
      canvas.drawBitmap(originalImage, 0, 0, null);
      //Draw in the gap
      Paint deafaultPaint = new Paint();
      canvas.drawRect(0, height, width, height + reflectionGap, deafaultPaint);
      //Draw in the reflection
      canvas.drawBitmap(reflectionImage,0, height + reflectionGap, null);

      //Create a shader that is a linear gradient that covers the reflection
      Paint paint = new Paint();
      LinearGradient shader = new LinearGradient(0, originalImage.getHeight(), 0,
      bitmapWithReflection.getHeight() + reflectionGap, 0x70ffffff, 0x00ffffff,
      TileMode.CLAMP);
      //Set the paint to use this shader (linear gradient)
      paint.setShader(shader);
      //Set the Transfer mode to be porter duff and destination in
      paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.DST_IN));
      //Draw a rectangle using the paint with our linear gradient
      canvas.drawRect(0, height, width,
      bitmapWithReflection.getHeight() + reflectionGap, paint);
      reflectionImage.recycle();
      return bitmapWithReflection;
   }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
    imageView.setImageBitmap(getRefelection(originalImage));
```

This is the line it is crashing on, and the reason is that `imageView` is `null`.

When you create a member variable such as the one you listed, you need to either create an object for it to point to, or set it to an already-created object.

In your case, I'm guessing you want to set it to one already created by your layout. Your layout XML should have some ImageView declared, but in order to get it in the Java code, you'll need to call `findViewById()`

If your XML is declared like this, with an `id`:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/my_image_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

Then you'll need to write the following before you can call `setImageBitmap()`:

```
imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);
```

Additionally, you **cannot make the findViewById** call until **after** you make the call to `setContentView()`, because that's the call that actually creates your `ImageView`.

Although, looking at your code a bit further, you probably don't need to do the reflection bit, or even the `setImageBitmap()` call, because you can specify the drawable directly in the XML (unless you want to change it when the program is running):

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/my_image_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/announcementbc"
    />
```

By adding the source line, and pointing it to your drawable, the `setContentView` call will automatically set the correct Bitmap on the ImageView.

Comment: If this solves your problem you can click the 'check mark' next to my answer to accept it as the solution.

Comment: So I thought this had the problem solved - but I must still be screwing something up. I tried a big bunch of permutations in terms of order so as to follow the rules you set above but I keep getting the null pointer exception still. And it seems to be more than one thing setting it off. Below is the final version I got to but as I said above I tried various permutations including eliminating the setImageBitmap call.

Comment: hmm somehow the second version of the code I posted below wound up above... so the code that says it's the latest failed code is what I am referring to in this comment..

Comment: Looks like you typed it into the wrong box. You put it in as an answer to your post, you'll want to do an 'edit' instead. It's also easier to tell what's changed that way, rather than manually looking between the two.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the latest failed code as per the comment above

public class Tile2 extends Activity{

```
// Bitmap originalImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.announcementbc);

ImageView imageView;
Bitmap originalImage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView (R.layout.tile);




    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivTile);
    originalImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.announcementbc);
    // ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(getReflection(originalImage));

    //Add the image to a linear layout and display it
    LinearLayout linLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    linLayout.addView(imageView, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

     // set LinearLayout as ContentView
     setContentView(linLayout);





}

public static Bitmap getReflection(Bitmap image)
   {
     //The gap we want between the reflection and the original image
       final int reflectionGap = 4;

       //Get you bit map from drawable folder
       Bitmap originalImage = image;


       int width = originalImage.getWidth();
       int height = originalImage.getHeight();


       //This will not scale but will flip on the Y axis
       Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
       matrix.preScale(1, -1);

       //Create a Bitmap with the flip matix applied to it.
       //We only want the bottom half of the image
       Bitmap reflectionImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalImage, 0, height/2, width, height/2, matrix, false);


       //Create a new bitmap with same width but taller to fit reflection
       Bitmap bitmapWithReflection = Bitmap.createBitmap(width
         , (height + height/2), Config.ARGB_8888);

      //Create a new Canvas with the bitmap that's big enough for
      //the image plus gap plus reflection
      Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmapWithReflection);
      //Draw in the original image
      canvas.drawBitmap(originalImage, 0, 0, null);
      //Draw in the gap
      Paint deafaultPaint = new Paint();
      canvas.drawRect(0, height, width, height + reflectionGap, deafaultPaint);
      //Draw in the reflection
      canvas.drawBitmap(reflectionImage,0, height + reflectionGap, null);

      //Create a shader that is a linear gradient that covers the reflection
      Paint paint = new Paint();
      LinearGradient shader = new LinearGradient(0, originalImage.getHeight(), 0,
        bitmapWithReflection.getHeight() + reflectionGap, 0x70ffffff, 0x00ffffff,
        TileMode.CLAMP);
      //Set the paint to use this shader (linear gradient)
      paint.setShader(shader);
      //Set the Transfer mode to be porter duff and destination in
      paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.DST_IN));
      //Draw a rectangle using the paint with our linear gradient
      canvas.drawRect(0, height, width,
        bitmapWithReflection.getHeight() + reflectionGap, paint);
      reflectionImage.recycle();
      return bitmapWithReflection;
   }
```

}

Comment: You should delete this and then modify your original post. And if it's still crashing somewhere, include the stacktrace from Logcat, and indicate what line it's complaining about.